# Android: How to save EditText converted to Array values and load them back in place

Tags: android, android-edittext, save, load

As a person who's new to Android programming, I have finally completed most of the functions I want my app to have except for the save/load system. (Although I still have to design the interface.)

Before I proceed, here is my code for the save button:

```
saveList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Save List");
            final EditText saveName = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            saveName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            builder.setView(saveName);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.cancel();
            }
     });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()                                                     
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_Text = saveName.getText().toString();
            }
     });
     builder.show();
}
```

Now, what I want to learn (know) is the method/code on how to save the values from my Array:

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
int idList[] = new int[]{R.id.textBox1, R.id.textBox2, R.id.textBox3,
                         R.id.textBox4, R.id.textBox5, R.id.textBox6};

for (int id : idList) {
    String stringList = ((EditText) findViewById(id)).getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(stringList)) {
         values.add(stringList);
    }
}

    myItems = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
```

And load those values into their respective places

(e.g myItems[0] should be placed in textBox1, myItems[1] into textBox2 and so on...).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

EDIT: My mistake about the question being misleading. I want to know how to save the values into a text file or an android given file and then load it for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restore back all the strings back into the EditTexts you need to maintain the mapping between the content and the EditText. In your case above, you are storing only the strings, that are not empty. So suppose your first EditText is empty, you won't store it in the `values`. But if you do that, your entire ordering will be messed up. You won't know which string to put where. The quickest workaround for this, is to store all the EditTexts string, even though if its empty. So your code will change to

```
    for (int id : idList) {
        String stringList = ((EditText) findViewById(id)).getText().toString();
        // Store everything in values
        values.add(stringList);
    }
    myItems = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
```

And then to load everything back, you can do something like

```
   for (int i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
        ((EditText) findViewById(idList[i])).setText(myItems[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Hello again! I should mention tho that if there are empty EditTexts, the app will not proceed to the next step unless filled with a value. And wow I just noticed the mistake in my question, I meant to save it for later use such as saving the list then exiting and then accessing it again.

Comment: That completely changes the requirement! In that case you should look into `SharedPreferences`. I won't write the code for that because it would be a lot of code and its straight forward. Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link! That's all I needed to know. I'll accept your answer since you have provided me one in here.